# How to redact a large rectangle of a PDF by iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I tried to use iTextSharp 5.5.9 to redact PDF files. The problem is when I redact a large rectangle field on a PDF, it can not save the file. This is the code:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(new FileStream(DesFile, FileMode.Open));

Stream fs = new FileStream(DesFile, FileMode.Open);

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs);

List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new List<PdfCleanUpLocation>();

cleanUpLocations.Add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(77f,77f,600f,600f), BaseColor.GRAY));

PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper); 

cleaner.CleanUp();

stamper.Close();

reader1.Close();
```

I use the http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.pdf to test, if I change the Rectangle to

```
new Rectangle(77f,77f,200f,200f)
```

It will work well... But when I change back the larger Rectangle:

```
new Rectangle(77f,77f,600f,600f)
```

It stops working. Please help!

Comment: It stops working is not a very descriptive error message. Does is throw an exception?

Comment: by 'redact' do you mean 'reduce' or 'shrink'?

Comment: It didn't throw any exception @nbokmans

Comment: @TaW I mean black some text out...

Comment: @SuperBerry I just tried to reproduce your issue but redaction worked alright in both cases. The only difference to your code is that I did not use the same file to read from and to write to. You might to try separating those files, too.

Comment: @mkl Thanks a lot!!! It works!!!! How can I choose your answer? thanks again :)

Comment: @SuperBerry I'll write an answer for it. The comment above is not a full-fledged answer.

Comment: @SuperBerry I added an answer based on my comment. Sorry it took me so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText development usually warns against stamping to the same file the underlying `PdfReader` reads from. If done as in the OP's code, reading and writing operations can get into each other's way, the results being unpredictable.

After using different files to read from and write to, the OP's solution started working.

---

If one first reads the source file into memory as a `byte[]` and then constructs the `PdfReader` from that array, it is possible to use the same file as output of a `PdfStamper` operating on that reader. But this pattern is not recommended either: If some problem occurs during stamping, the original file contents may already have been removed, so you have neither the unstamped original PDF nor a stamped result PDF.

It might be embarrassing to have to explain to the client that his documents are completely gone for good...