# iTextSharp 5.5.9 Redaction - Object Reference not found

Tags: c#, itext

I pulled the code from [How to redact a large rectangle of a PDF by iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542052/how-to-redact-a-large-rectangle-of-a-pdf-by-itextsharp)

And generated:

```
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader;
    reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(new System.IO.FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(txtPDFFile.Text);
    System.IO.Stream fsOut = new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"redacted.pdf"), System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, fsOut);
List<iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new    List<iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation>();
        cleanUpLocations.Add(new iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(77f, 77f, 200f, 200f), iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GRAY));
        iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, stamper);
        cleaner.CleanUp();
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

So I took from the linked article that I should use differing input files which I was doing.

But at the cleaner.CleanUp() I get an object reference not found:

```
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor pdfContentStreamProcessor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.FormXObjectDoHandler.HandleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfStream stream, PdfIndirectReference refi)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.DisplayXObject(PdfName xobjectName)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.Do.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor pdfContentStreamProcessor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.CleanUpPage(Int32 pageNum, IList`1 cleanUpLocations)
   at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.CleanUp()
   at Com.EDS.DocSol.PDFExtract.PDFExtractForm.btnRedaction_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Users\me\Code\PDFExtract\PDFExtract\PDFExtractForm.cs:line 106
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Com.EDS.DocSol.PDFExtract.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Users\me\Code\PDFExtract\PDFExtract\Program.cs:line 140
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I can't see why.  The rectangle I haven't changed.  I'm unsure if there actually has to be something at that location.  I had some code that would add an annotation first, then I was trying to apply it.  But it would also get the same object reference error.

In the code above....do I need to create a redaction annotation first before applying, or is this code choosing the box I want to redact and applying it all in one pass.

The Rectangle I want (it's an address block), is actually: iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(45, 650, 200, 750);

Comment: Please share a sample PDF to reproduce the issue. `PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke` is too big a method to guess where an object is unexpectedly null.

Comment: I had to go through and desensitise the PDF document.  But here is a sample.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h4cuyqvmv9rso6/Document.pdf?dl=0

Also I tried changing the code to the following:
`iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor(stamper);`

(removed the cleanup locations)  This seems to get a Object Reference not found on contructor....I wonder if that is invalid...and that the cleanup locations must be present?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, using your code and changing the rectangle coordinates to `45, 650, 200, 750` as indicated by your question and the file paths as present on my system. Applying it to your sample file unfortunately worked properly. Thus, either there is something special about your setup you have not mentioned yet or you repaired an issue in your original PDF file when you *desensitised* it.

Comment: Concerning *This seems to get a Object Reference not found on contructor....I wonder if that is invalid...and that the cleanup locations must be present?* - Cleanup locations must be present either explicitly (as in the code in your question) or implicitly as redaction annotations in the PDF. Your PDF contains no annotations at all which might give rise to that "Object Reference not found" error.

Comment: Regarding the constructor - ok now I understand.  I also have code that creates an Annotation first, saves it then opens again runs cleanup with no locations.  The constructor gets the error.

Comment: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text, FileMode.Open));
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
{
  // Add the annotations
  int page = 1;
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(45, 650, 200, 750);
  PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, rect);
  annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
  stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
} //Using`

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the OP's original observation, the *object reference not found*

```
at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor pdfContentStreamProcessor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.FormXObjectDoHandler.HandleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfStream stream, PdfIndirectReference refi)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.DisplayXObject(PdfName xobjectName)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.Do.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.Invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor pdfContentStreamProcessor, PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.InvokeOperator(PdfLiteral oper, List`1 operands)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
```

occurs while the cleanup processor parses the content stream of a form xobject: Some instruction in the content stream appears to be invalid (most likely the instruction parameters are invalid), i.e. the PDF very likely simply is broken to start with.

This behavior cannot be reproduced with the *desensitised* version of the OP's document. In particular that desensitized version only contains one form xobject on each page which does not intersect the redaction area. When extending the redaction area to partially intersect the form xobject, one does get an exception. But it is a different one clearly indicating that `System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage` cannot handle the format of the bitmap image shown in the form xobject.

Thus, the invalid form xobject content seems to have been removed in the desensitizing process. For hardening the cleanup code against the issue at hand, therefore, the original document is needed.

---

In a comment the OP indicated he also tried to call the cleanup process in a different way, i.e. by adding redaction annotations to the PDF and then calling the cleanup process without `PdfCleanUpLocation`. He adds the redaction annotations like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text, FileMode.Open));
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
{
    // Add the annotations
    int page = 1;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(45, 650, 200, 750);
    PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, rect);
    annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
    stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
} //Using
```

Cleanup now also runs into an *object reference not found* situation, but this time

```
at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnot(Int32 page, Int32 annotIndex, PdfDictionary annotDict)
at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnots(Int32 page, PdfDictionary pageDict)
at iTextSharp.xtra.iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.ExtractLocationsFromRedactAnnots()
```

The cause in this case is a bug in the cleanup code. Redaction annotations generated by e.g. Adobe Reader usually contain an additional parameter, **QuadPoints**, which contains a number of quadrilaterals which specify the area inside the annotation rectangle to actually redact; if this parameter is not present, the whole rectangle is to be redacted.

iTextSharp in this context has this code:

```
PdfArray quadPoints = annotDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.QUADPOINTS);

if (quadPoints.Size != 0) {
    markedRectangles.AddRange(TranslateQuadPointsToRectangles(quadPoints));
} else { 
    ... add a range for the annotation rectangle ...
}
```

Unfortunately, if the annotation has no **QuadPoints**, `annotDict.GetAsArray` returns `null` and the evaluation of `quadPoints.Size` fails with an exception. It should be

```
if (quadPoints != null && quadPoints.Size != 0) {
```

instead.

The OP can work around this by adding **QuadPoints** entry with an empty array to his redaction:

```
...
annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
annotation.Put(PdfName.QUADPOINTS, new PdfArray()); // <<<<<<<<
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
...
```

**Beware:** This is merely a workaround for this iTextSharp issue, it should not be done if the PDF with the annotations is for other use. Strictly speaking, an empty **QuadPoints** entry indicates that nothing is to be redacted.

---

As an aside, there is an issue in the OP's code: When creating file streams for the PdfStamper to write to, he uses `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`:

```
System.IO.Stream fsOut = new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path,"redacted.pdf"), System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

or

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(txtPDFFile.Text + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
```

If there already is a file with that name which furthermore turns out to be longer than the new PDF, the result will have the size of the old file with the old content still in the extra space. I.e. the new file effectively has dangling trash content which makes an invalid PDF which e.g. Adobe Reader offers to repair.

In general one should use `FileMode.Create` instead. From its documentation:

> `FileMode.Create` is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use `System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew`; otherwise, use `System.IO.FileMode.Truncate`.

Comment: Hi thanks for that detailed analysis.  I'll try a few other PDF files that I have here...but unfortunately cannot share the original ones as they're from a commercial use application.

Regarding the PDF having issues, I do use itext in other aspects (merging and the application of a watermark), but are you saying that for the purposes of redaction they're invalid?

Comment: *"but are you saying that for the purposes of redaction they're invalid?"* - no, i merely say that there is a bug. There is hardly any piece of software without bugs. Furthermore, the bug results in an exception, so it does not create a false impression of a successful execution. Thus, it's not the worst possible kind of bug.

Comment: Btw I added:
`annotation.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Redact"));
annotation.Put(PdfName.QUADPOINTS, new PdfArray()); // <<<<<<<<
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);`
as mentioned, and that 2nd method worked.  I found a number of PDFs here that were redactable.  There's a certain scenario that doesn't seem to work.